# Is "dropped to the floor" a completely natural thing to write here?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> The terrorist was hanging from a balcony two floors up, trying to pull himself up. The police officers shot at the terrorist, who dropped to the floor and died.

(this is going on inside a shopping mall)

Is "dropped to the floor" a completely natural thing to write here?

Comment: I would find _fell_ more natural than _dropped_. When _drop_ is used of oneself, it usually implies intention.

Answer (score 2):

As Colin said, the more natural thing here is 'fell'. Normally one would use 'dropped' to mean 'he let go and fell'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it natural? I guess that is all up to interpretation. As others have said, “dropped” does sound like an intentional act on the part of the terrorist. Where as the sentence, “The police officer dropped the terrorist with one shot.”, sounds more like the intentional act by the officer. On the other hand, the terrorist could have intentionally dropped to the floor to avoid the shot, but failed.